# insert and receive the data from MySQL through Android using PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, eclipse

I am getting the errors like while running this app.
"Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value

this is my register_user.java

```
package com.iwantnew.www;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class register_user extends Activity{
    // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText signup_username;
    EditText signup_email;
    EditText signup_password;
    Button registerBtn;
    TextView registerErrorMsg;

    // url to create new product
        private static String url_create_users = "http://10.0.2.2/http://10.0.2.2/android_iwant/signup_success.php";
        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup_form);
        // Edit Text
                signup_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_username);
                signup_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_email);
                signup_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_password);                
                registerBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regiserBtn);

                // button click event
                registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // creating new product in background thread
                        new CreateNewUser().execute();
                    }
                });

    }
    class CreateNewUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(register_user.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Users..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            /*String username = signup_username.getText().toString();
            String email =  signup_email.getText().toString();
            String password = signup_password.getText().toString();*/

            //Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", signup_username.getText().toString()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",signup_email.getText().toString()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", signup_password.getText().toString()));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_users,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created users
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create users

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

}
```

This is the JSONParser.java. this is the data parsing class of android

```
package com.iwantnew.www;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET method
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }          

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

this is the PHP code(signup_success.php)

```
<?php
// array for JSON response
$response = array();
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';


    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

     $uuid = uniqid('', true);
        $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$username', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");
        // check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            // get user details 
            $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
            // return user details
            return mysql_fetch_array($result);
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        $result =  mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(name,email,password) VALUES ('$username','$email,$password')");
     // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "successfully signed Up.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);}
        else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);

}
?>
```

Comment: Debug and post this `sb.toString();`

Comment: Please post what you get from `BufferReader` as a response.

Answer (score 0):

Error parsing data org.json.JSONException

This error is because paring json response is failed because the response from the server side is not what is expected.

In your PHP Script i saw an problem

```
// check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            // get user details 
            $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
            // return user details
            return mysql_fetch_array($result);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

In this block there is return statement in if and else both so the code which is written after that is not reachable.
I don't get it what the bellow code do but if data is inserted you have to use json_encode for response in form of json.
So for that you have to remove return from if block

```
// check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            // get user details 
            $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
            // return user details
           echo json_encode(mysql_fetch_array($result));
           exit;               
        }
```

Some advice wile using api
 1. First check your result from web by postmen and confirm that the output is as per your requirement.
 2. In android use debugging to find out the error.

Debugging your code is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, issues into json format. let me give some example for how to create json.

1. `$dt=array('key' => 'value');`
   Response/output:

   {key:value}
2. `$dt=array(array('key' => 'value'),array('key2' => 'value2'))` 
   Response/output:

   [{key:value},{key2:values2}]